# Usefulness of grappling feats for Druids

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, grapple

Basically I'm interested in knowing if improved unarmed strike/improved grapple/greater grapple are effective feats for a wild shaped druid. Or if the wild shape form is already adequate to grapple foes without having to spend multiple feats on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you gain access to [Beast Shape II](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape/), which should be at 6th level for the vanilla druid, you turn into creatures that have the [Grab](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-Grab-Ex-) ability.

> **Grab (Ex):**
>
> If a creature with this special attack hits with the indicated attack (usually a claw or bite attack), it deals normal damage and attempts to **start a grapple as a free action without provoking an attack of opportunity**. Unless otherwise noted, grab can only be used against targets of a size equal to or smaller than the creature with this ability. (...)
>
> Creatures with the grab special attack receive a **+4 bonus on combat maneuver checks made to start and maintain a grapple**.

So, unless you really feel you need the extra +2 from [Improved Grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-grapple-combat-final/), you do not need to spend two feats simply to be an effective grappler.

[Greater Grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-grapple-combat-final/), however, is an upgrade to your grapple checks, but again, your real benefit from the feat is the ability to **maintain a grapple as a move action** instead of a *standard action*.

This will cost you three feats, from which you will only benefit partially from one and recieve the normal benefits of the other. Again, on a class that does not gain any bonus feats, so investing on **grapple feats are not very useful for druids**.

Comment: You have to note that with greater grapple you can maintain twice a turn, which means you can do the effects of pin, damage, move, etc. twice on your turn. Get a form with constrict and you trigger it twice. This goes even more nuts with rapid grapple feat.